# BigQuery API for access log - I'm losing data

Tags: python, rest, api, logging, google-bigquery

i have doing access log to a MySQL table, but recently it became too much for MySQL. Then, i decided to save in Google BigQuery. I don't know if it is the better option, but it seems to viable. Anyone has comments about that? Okay...

I started to integrate to Google BigQuery, i made an small application with Flask (a Python framework). I created endpoints to receive data and send to BigQuery. Now my general application sends data to a URL which is pointed to my Flask application, that for your turn, sends to BigQuery. Any observation or suggestion here?

Finally my problem, sometimes i'm losing data. I made an script to test my general application to see the results, i ran the script it for many times and noticed that i lost some data, because sometimes the same data are being saved and sometimes not. Someone has some idea what can be happening? And most important.. How can i prevent to lose data in that case? How my application can be prepared to notice that data wasn't seved to Google BigQuery and then treat it, like to try again?

I am using google-cloud-python library (reference: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html#tables).

My code:

```
client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)
table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)
SCHEMA = [SchemaField(**field) for field in schema]
errors = client.create_rows(table_ref, [row], SCHEMA)
```

That is all

Comment: You need to detail how you load/stream data maybe in that implementation process there is a bug, like in streaming inserts some rows can timeout, but others persisted, and you need to retry only the rows that indicated a timeout.

Comment: @Pentium10 i gave more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I expected, you don't handle `errors`. Make sure you handle and understand how streaming insert works. If you stream 1000 rows, and 56 fail, you get that back, and you need to retry only 56 rows. Also `insertId` is important.

[Streaming Data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery-stream-data-ruby)

Comment: Do you mean **insertId** (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#streaming) ? How could i have an unique insertId for each row?

Comment: you can have it computed using microtime and some guid